# error: port is not open in raspberry pi

Tags: port, gsm, uart

I have connected gsm sim900 to raspberry pi and enabled uart serial port as:
in terminal : $ sudo nano /boot/config.txt then i added enable_uart=1 to the config text.
as the above changes i see this answer : 
[error] [serial out : sendSMS] ERROR: port is not open
[info] serial port /dev/ttyAMA0 opened at 9600 baud 8N1

the sendSMS is my serial output name that runs first in the beginning. i don't know what's the problem maybe it has delay or something else but i receive no reply for my at commands.
please help me

Comment: Describe in detail the steps you actually did for your RPi, rather than just provide a link to some article for RPi3.

Comment: I edited the post without link and with more explain

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem. the error was becouse of connections problem. and as my change said in question is eanagh